# Do not see the JButtons(JLabel) i added in my JFrame

Tags: java, swing

So I'm having a class called Menu which extends JLabel and has a constructor  which adds 3 JButtons to itself.

```
 public Menu() {
    this.add(jbutton1);
    this.add(jbutton2);
    this.add(jbutton3);
}
```

I have another class called GUI which extends JFrame and adds the JLabel to its contentPane.

```
public GUI() {
    Menu menu = new Menu();
    getContentPane().add(menu);
    setSize(300,200);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

The main method of GUI just looks like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    GUI gui = new GUI();
}
```

So what I wanted is a JFrame with 3 JButtons in it (going to do more stuff later one). Instead I just got a blank JFrame. Why don't I see the JLabel with the 3 JButtons in it I added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're forgetting layout managers which are key to controlling how components are added to and sized by containers. JLabels are not used to being used as a container and holding other components and so come by default with a `null` layout -- no layout at all, making you the programmer responsible for sizing and positioning any added component.

Solutions:

- Set your JButton's sizes and positions yourself -- a *very* bad solution since it leads to GUI's that only work well on one platform and that are difficult to debug and maintain
- Or give the container (here the JLabel) a decent layout manager.
- Or use another container, such as a JPanel, one that already has a layout manager, as the contentPanel. There are ways of getting a JPanel to display an image including overriding its paintComponent method.

You can find the layout manager tutorial here: [Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html), and you can find links to the Swing tutorials and to other Swing resources here: [Swing Info](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing).

Comment: Ouh my bad, in my head i was using JPanels the entire time, i dont know why i used JLabels and did not even notice that...